# Accessing the last 5 objects of a particular column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working in a dataframe in R and I want to access the last 5 objects of a particular column in a dataframe.How do i go about it??

Answer (score 3):

One option is `tail(dataframe$column, 5)`